# how can I migrate google.signIn()?

Tags: angular, google-oauth, google-signin, google-one-tap

I'm using the library angularx-social-login in my angular app, but now there's an error in the console about 'deprecated'
Then I try to use

```
return gapi.auth2
  .getAuthInstance()
  .signIn({
    scope:
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.read-only',
  })
  .then(
    () => {
      console.log('Sign-in successful');
      this.loadClient();

    },
    (err: any) => {
      console.error('Error signing in', err);
    }
  );
```

But is the same error... so what's the new form to sign in with google in angular?

Answer (score 0):

Use Google API Javascript client

```
https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client
```

See also

```
https://developers.google.com/identity
```